# Define constraints on python for Backtrack

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, backtracking

I must implement Backtracking on python with the constraints as  functions f(A, a, B, b) that returns true if neighbors A, B satisfy the constraint when they have values A=a, B=b. I have to resolve the problem:

Send + more = money

but i do not know how to implements the constraints. I know that:

D + E = Y + 10*C1

C1 + N + R = E + 10*C1

C2 + E + O = N + C3*10

C3 + S + M = O + 10*C4

C4 = M

but how can I implement these constraints as a function f(A,a,B,b)?

Comment: Did you try to look anything up?

Comment: Does it have to be done in python? Are you constrained to use a specific library or none?

Comment: Yes, it has to be done in python and i can't use any library

Answer (score 0):

Backtracking is a general algorithm for finding all (or some) solutions to some computational problems, notably constraint satisfaction problems, that incrementally builds candidates to the solutions, and abandons each partial candidate c ("backtracks") as soon as it determines that c cannot possibly be completed to a valid solution

Comment: Are you really answering the question ?

Comment: No, actually he didn't answer the question